# Android: formatting standalone month

Tags: java, android, date

I have a problem formatting standalone month for android.

In documentation exist a list of used symbols for SimpleDateFormat class.
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

But when I'm trying to call this

```
SimpleDateFormat llll = new SimpleDateFormat("LLLL", calendarLocale);
llll.format(myCalendar.getTime());
```

I got exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character - 'L'
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validateFormat(SimpleDateFormat.java:379)
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validatePattern(SimpleDateFormat.java:435)
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:499)
```

From my point it seems that documentation is WRONG. Or am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have ICU jar files ?

Here is the note from the API documentation --

**The two pattern characters L and c are ICU-compatible extensions, not available in the RI. These are necessary for correct localization in languages such as Russian that distinguish between, say, "June" and "June 2010".**

http://site.icu-project.org/

Comment: Oh great! I've didn't noticed this remark. 
But ICU jar is a little bit heavy (7Mb) for android device.
It's easier to make switch statement for russian :)